# How to work with RowVersion and derived class via discriminators

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

We have a data model with various models that have been derived from our base class. Some similar models we have given an alternate base class (that in itself has our common base class as base) and many of them use `HasDiscriminator` to have a single table

```cs
public abstract class ModelBase
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public uint RowVersion { get; set; }
    // And some more global properties.
}

public abstract class Relation : ModelBase
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    // And some more relation properties.
}

public abstract class Person : Relation
{
    public string PersonNumber { get; set; }
    public TimePeriod ValidityPeriod { get; set; }
    // And some more person properties.
}

public abstract class Business : Relation
{
    public int BusinessNumber { get; set; }
    // And some more relation properties.
}

// And some more models derived from ModelBase with each its own table.
```

Both `Person` and `Business` are stored in the same table. We use `IEntityTypeConfiguration<>` implementations for configuring these entities.

When running `dotnet ef migrations add "Add RowVersion"` we get the following exception:

> Entity type 'Business' doesn't contain a property mapped to the store-generated concurrency token column 'validityperiod__tablesharingconcurrencytokenconvention_rowvers~' which is used by another entity type sharing the table 'relations'. Add a store-generated property to 'Business' which is mapped to the same column; it may be in shadow state.

This seems to me as a valid construction, is there a way to make this work?